# Compile error for last column in VBA for command button

Tags: excel, vba

Receiving compile error for - I have only 1 worksheet and created command button for code then wrote this code and received a compile error? I have data in A1:H16 my test sample msgbox returned the answer for range (A1:H16)

```
Sub SampleBox()
MsgBox UsedRange.Address
End Sub
```

But this code for the command button returns compile error message

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Last_Column = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

MsgBox Last_Column
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Compile error and Variable not defined

Comment: `Dim Last_Column As Long`.

Comment: Thanks Ben and fantastic it's resolved. Cheers for your help